# How to call nested program in cmd

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

Program A(cmd.exe \C)   (Takes 1 argument)

Program B: (Takes 1 or more arguments)

C1,C2,C3, ... : A list of agruments

If I type `A B C1 C2 C3` in cmd prompt,
The desired interpretation is

`A (B (C1 C2 C3))`                  (C is the arguments to B,   B is the argument to A)

But NOT AS  `A (B) (C1) (C2) (C3)` (B,C1,C2, C3, .... are arguments to A)

How should I escape / redirect/pipe in cmd prompt?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true), you can use the `|` operator for pipes.

And you will need to rewrite your command as:

```
B C1 C2 C3 | A
```

Hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE**

since you updated your question, I guess you are trying to do something like:

```
cmd.exe /C B C1 C2 C3
```

you can escape special characters with `^`

or try to quote the string like this:

```
cmd.exe /C "B C1 C2 C3"
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you are having problem with `cmd.exe /C` and quotes (e.g. B, C1, C2, C3 contains space), you should enclose the whole command with another pair of quotes

```
cmd.exe /C ""B" "C1" "C2" "C3""
```

FYI, in the `Processing quotation marks` section in [Microsoft's documentation on cmd.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true):

> If you specify /c or /k, cmd processes the remainder of string and
>   quotation marks are preserved only if all of the following conditions
>   are met:
>
> - You do not use /s.
> - You use exactly one set of quotation marks.
> - You do not use any special characters within the quotation marks (for example: &<>( ) @ ^ |).
> - You use one or more white-space characters within the quotation marks.
> - The string within quotation marks is the name of an executable file.
>
> If the previous conditions are not met, string is processed by
>   examining the first character to verify whether or not it is an
>   opening quotation mark. If the first character is an opening quotation
>   mark, it is stripped along with the closing quotation mark. Any text
>   following the closing quotation marks is preserved.

You may want to read [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) too:

> To launch a batch script with spaces in the Program Path requiring
>   "quotes"
>
> `CMD /k ""c:\batch files\test.cmd" "Parameter 1 with space" "Parameter2
>   with space""`